# Make the wrapper div cover all posisioned divs inside

Tags: html, css

Please help me one way to make the parent div cover all the div inside it. These ones inside have position attributes? Please edit to my fiddle of my bellow comment.

Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TrangDinhVan/3xw6r6hf/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add "padding bottom" to contain the absolute child div.

```
.parent { 
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Padding bottom will contain the amount of "top: 50px;" you set for the .child-2 div. Since the child-2 has absolute value, you will have to change the padding-bottom value with the same value of the .child-2 top value. Sorry for my English.

Check this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3xw6r6hf/10/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.parent div{
code here
}
```

the added space and div selects all divs inside the parent container.

If I am understanding you correctly that is. Please let me know and ill help you accordingly.

EDIT: your issue is that you are using absolute positioning on your child2. Its in a relatively positioned parent so it won't mix well.

Comment: Im not totally understanding what you are wanting. You want to control both children of the "parent" div and style them both at the same time?

Comment: I want the green box covers all the box child 1 and child 2, now the box child 2 is outside of green box
Please view  [my template](http://jsfiddle.net/TrangDinhVan/3xw6r6hf/1)

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/3xw6r6hf/2/  I removed the position:absolute as it was causing your entire body to collapse into one line.

Comment: Sorry I mean I want the green box covers both child 2 in layout, not the way arrange css code.

Comment: so from the updated fiddle, what are you looking to achieve? This? http://jsfiddle.net/3xw6r6hf/9/  You can't use absolute positioning on child 2 as its in a relatively positioned container. Remove the position:absolute and you will be fine.